# Writing ELF headers in Radare?

Tags: radare2, elf

Reading [Keith Makan's, *"Introduction to the ELF Format : The ELF Header"*](https://blog.k3170makan.com/2018/09/introduction-to-elf-format-elf-header.html), he modifies `e_entry`,

> The `e_entry` field lists the offset in the file where the program should start executing.Normally it points to your _start method (of course if you compiled it with the usual stuff). You can point the e_entry anywhere you like, as an example I'm going to show that you can call a function that would other wise be impossible under normal execution.

Also documented in [`man 5 elf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/elf), I'm wondering if Radare has any functionality to rewrite ELF-specific headers or if writing the bits manually is the current way to do this? For example, I know it'll show the entry point with `ie`.

Comment: You absolutely want to do this with radare2? If not, have a look at the bfd project (used by binutils).

Comment: @0xC0000022L I'm not sure there is a way to do this, generally speaking I assume that Radare can't do something, and then I ask and I find out it can (a huge value of this site). I assume it can only parse ELF. If it can only parse ELF, I think a workaround is a great contribution because I'm pretty spankin new to RE, and I'm sure others are testing the waters just like me. If Radare grows the ability later, I will just come back and mark the newer answer as chosen.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, obviously you can. radare2 has built-in features to handle binary headers. This including reading, parsing and modifying the headers of the binary. And this is not different for `elf` or `pe` files, it will work great with both.

### TL;DR

```
$ ./example.elf
[*] you ran this binary!

$ r2 -w -nn example.elf
[0x00000000]> .pf.elf_header.entry=0x0000063a
[0x00000000]> q

$ ./example.elf
[*] wow how did you manage to call this?
```

---

### Creating our test file

As described in the article you linked in your question, it is easy to create a binary with a function that should never be executed under regular circumstances. Here's the exact code that was used in the linked article:

```
$ cat example.c

#include <stdio.h>


void never_call (void) {
    printf ("[*] wow how did you manage to call this?\n");
    return;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    printf ("[*] you ran this binary!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the function `never_call` would, well... never be called. The program would execute the entrypoint which would execute the `main` function and will return.

Now let's compile it using the command line used in the article, and execute the program:

```
$ gcc -Wall -o example.elf example.c
$ ./example.elf
[*] you ran this binary!
```

As we said, only `main()` was executed. Now let's open the binary in radare2 to see the magic happens.

---

### radare2 time!

**Finding the address of the function**

As you requested, we want to modify the entry point of the binary by modifying the pointed address in the elf header to be our `never_call` function. So first, we need to find the address of `never_call` in the binary.

```
$ r2 example.elf
[0x00000530]> f~never_call
0x0000063a 19 sym.never_call
```

We can see that the function `never_call` is at address *0x0000063a*. As you probably know by now, the `f` command is used to list the [flags](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/basic_commands/flags.html) that was marked by radare2, this including symbols as functions names. Then, we used `~` which is r2's internal *grep* and grepped for the relevant function.

**Parsing the ELF Header**

First, we need to seek to address `0` using `s 0` and then and only then we can parse the header with a new command `pf`. The command `pf` is used to print formatted data such as structures, enums, and types. Let's load the format definition for `elf64` using `pfo elf64` and use the `pf.` command to list the format definitions:

```
[0x00002400]> s 0        # Seek to pos 0 in the binary

[0x00000000]> pfo elf64  # Load a Format Definition File for elf

[0x00000000]> pf.
pf.elf_header [16]z[2]E[2]Exqqqxwwwwww ident (elf_type)type (elf_machine)machine version entry phoff shoff flags ehsize phentsize phnum shentsize shnum shstrndx

pf.elf_phdr [4]E[4]Eqqqqqq (elf_p_type)type (elf_p_flags)flags offset vaddr paddr filesz memsz align

pf.elf_shdr x[4]E[8]Eqqqxxqq name (elf_s_type)type (elf_s_flags_64)flags addr offset size link info addralign entsize
```

One of the loaded definitions is the `elf_header` which holds the structure for the elf64 header. We can print the header like this:

```
[0x00000000]> pf.elf_header
     ident : 0x00000000 = .ELF...
      type : 0x00000010 = type (enum elf_type) = 0x3 ; ET_DYN
   machine : 0x00000012 = machine (enum elf_machine) = 0x3e ; EM_AMD64
   version : 0x00000014 = 0x00000001
     entry : 0x00000018 = (qword)0x0000000000000530
     phoff : 0x00000020 = (qword)0x0000000000000040
     shoff : 0x00000028 = (qword)0x0000000000001948
     flags : 0x00000030 = 0x00000000
    ehsize : 0x00000034 = 0x0040
 phentsize : 0x00000036 = 0x0038
     phnum : 0x00000038 = 0x0009
 shentsize : 0x0000003a = 0x0040
     shnum : 0x0000003c = 0x001d
  shstrndx : 0x0000003e = 0x001c
```

As you can see, radare2 printed the elf64 header in a readable format so now we can see that `entry`, at 0x18, points to `0x530` which is our original entrypoint function. We can verify it by using `ie`, a radare2 command to print the entrypooint:

```
[0x00000000]> ie
[Entrypoints]
vaddr=0x00000530 paddr=0x00000530 baddr=0x00000000 laddr=0x00000000 haddr=0x00000018 hvaddr=0x00000018 type=program
```

Indeed, you can see that the entry point is 0x530 and the `haddr`, which is the header address, is 0x18.

**Modifying the entry point**

In order to modify this entry, we would need to open the file in writing mode. We can simply execute `oo+` from our current session in order to re-open the file in write mode, or use the `-w` argument to `radare2`.

Then, we can simply use the `pf` command to write to the parsed structure the address of `never_call` function.

```
[0x00000000]> oo+
[0x00000000]> pf.elf_header.entry=0x0000063a
wv8 0x0000063a @ 0x00000018
```

This printed us a radare2 command to execute which will modify this address in the header. We can either execute it ourselves or use the `.` command to "interpret the output of the command as r2 commands".

So instead of executing `wv8 ...`, we will simply do:

```
[0x00000000]> .pf.elf_header.entry=0x0000063a
```

And now `entry` should be overridden with 0x63a which is our `never_call` function.

```
[0x00000000]> pf.elf_header
     ident : 0x00000000 = .ELF...
      type : 0x00000010 = type (enum elf_type) = 0x3 ; ET_DYN
   machine : 0x00000012 = machine (enum elf_machine) = 0x3e ; EM_AMD64
   version : 0x00000014 = 0x00000001
     entry : 0x00000018 = (qword)0x000000000000063a
     phoff : 0x00000020 = (qword)0x0000000000000040
     shoff : 0x00000028 = (qword)0x0000000000001948
     flags : 0x00000030 = 0x00000000
    ehsize : 0x00000034 = 0x0040
 phentsize : 0x00000036 = 0x0038
     phnum : 0x00000038 = 0x0009
 shentsize : 0x0000003a = 0x0040
     shnum : 0x0000003c = 0x001d
  shstrndx : 0x0000003e = 0x001c

[0x00000000]> pf.elf_header.entry
     entry : 0x00000018 = (qword)0x000000000000063a
```

**Executing**

Great! We can now exit radare and execute the program.

```
$ ./example.elf
[*] wow how did you manage to call this?
```

---

### Last words

This long answer explained every step in the way but can really be narrowed to a simple command `.pf.elf_header.entry=0x0000063a` which sets the `entry` in the elf header to be the desired address. In the **TL;DR** version I demonstrated the use of `-w` to open the binary in `write-mode` and the use of `-nn` to load the binary structure (`pfo elf64`, etc...). So simply, opening radare2 like this `r2 -w -nn example.elf` and executing `.pf.elf_header.entry=<address>` would solve your problem.

Don't be afraid to ask how to do things in radare2. Although it is quite a scary framework, it is really powerful and with proper knowledge, can do much more things than seems like at first.

### Read more

- radare.today | [Parsing a fileformat with radare2](http://radare.today/posts/parsing-a-fileformat-with-radare2/)
- r2book | [Types](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/analysis/types.html)

Comment: Wow, this is really cool. From the UI standpoint, it would be nice if the `.pf.elf_header.entry=0x0000063a` didn't write to `$$` but to `@ 0`. Got it right the second time though.

Comment: I just used this to answer another question on the site, thanks again for answering all my questions on re.se. I'll keep them coming. =) https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/19936/22669

Answer (score 2):

*I don't think this feature is supported according to the [source code](https://github.com/radare/radare2/search?q=%22e_entry%22).*
Edit: I was wrong, sorry about that.

However, if you really need a library/tool to do that, I recommend [LIEF](https://github.com/lief-project/LIEF).